# What's the new name for map2 in Scalaz 7?

Tags: scala, functor, scalaz, scalaz7

Jordan West in [this presentation](https://youtu.be/S_l95GIDCM0?t=9m12s) from Scalamachine clearly speaks about `map2` function. Turns out the function was [available in Scalaz 6](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.0-1-6.0.1/doc.sxr/scalaz/MA.scala.html) but I can't find it or any equivalent in Scalaz 7.

E.g. I would like to be able to run this code:

```
List(Some(1), Some(2)).map2(_ + 1)
```

and get as a result

```
List(Some(2), Some(3))
```

Where can I find this function in Scalaz 7?

**EDIT:**
Ideally, I would like to be able to execute any function `f: A => B` on `l: List[Option[A]]`

```
l.map2(f)
```

And get `List[Option[B]]` with the intuitive semantics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simplify nested map calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284131/how-to-simplify-nested-map-calls)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, there does not seem to exist such function in Scalaz 7 but there is a nice way around using Monad Transformers:

```
OptionT[List, Int](List(Some(1), Some(2))).map(_ + 1).run

// List(Some(2), Some(3))
```

or in the case of `l: List[Option[A]]`

```
OptionT[List, A](l).map(f).run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the applicative syntax instead:

```
scala> List(Some(1), Some(2)) <*> List((x:Option[Int]) => x |+| Some(1))
res0: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(2), Some(3))
```

Scalaz 7 is a different beast compared to Scalaz 6.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't found `map2` in scalaz 7 and the applicative approach by @I.K. is the most similar I could think. However in this situation where the "shape of the list" doesn't change, I would `map` and `mappend`:

```
List(1.some, 2.some) map (_ |+| 1.some)
res: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(2), Some(3))
```

Of course if the default operation assigned to the type is not the desired one, then I would use an exiting `Tag` from scalaz or a custom `implicit`.

**EDIT**

I have just noticed your answer: the other-way-round expected result could be achieved using `traverse`

```
List(1.some, 2.some, 3.some) traverseU (_ |+| 1.some)
Some(List(2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Yeah, this is fun but it's not going to work for `List[Option[S]]` where `S` doesn't form a semigroup, right ?

Comment: That is correct, if `S` doesn't form a `semigroup` , `Option[S]` doesn't too

Comment: `Please consider adding a comment if you think this response can be improved`